# JavaFXML Upon completion of background process i want to to hide splash and display the main scene

Tags: multithreading, performance, asynchronous, javafx, fxml

Disclaimer--Forgive my terminology it may not be spot on.

Fully functioning application, **I wan to improve functionality of threads and performance**

when run, it will display a splash screen for around 40 seconds and then displays the main scene layout.
while splash is displayed it will start a command line process to write output to a .txt file this process takes 30 seconds to complete.

**Problem** -- if the command line process is not completed when control is passed to the main scene
the main scene wont have anything to read from the .txt file.

I want the  main scene layout to display as soon as the command line process has completed writing the output to file. Not to wait 40 seconds and hope the command process has completed.

**Main class Loader**

public class SplashLoader extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Splash.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

**SplashController**
public class SplashController implements Initializable {

```
static String ping = "";

@FXML AnchorPane ap;

//Loads the Speedtest.fxml into the rootpane to be displayed set to run 40 seconds after the splash screen has displayed
class ShowSpeedTestScreen extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30000);

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                Parent root = null; 
                try {  
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SpeedTest.fxml"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setTitle("It Help");
                stage.show();                   
                ap.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            });                
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
}

//On initialization of the splash screen
//Start network speedtest average 30 sec run time
//Create seperate thread to run in 40 seconds that sets the Speedtest.fxml layout to the stage via ShowSpeedTestScreen() class
//It is important that the runtime command has 30 seconds to finish its process else the speedtest will not be able to retrieve the download and upload speeds
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "mkdir C:\\Temp | fast -u > C:\\Temp\\speedtest.txt\"");
    try {Process process = builder.start();}
    catch (IOException ex) {}

    ping = checkPing();

    new ShowSpeedTestScreen().start();       
}
```

}

**Main Layout Controller**

public class SpeedTestController implements Initializable {

```
//Nodes on the Layout from "SpeedTest.fxml"
@FXML
private Label lblDownloadNum;
@FXML
private Label lblPingNum;
@FXML
private Label lblTitle;
@FXML
private Label lblUploadNum;
@FXML
private Label lblmbps;
@FXML
private Label lblmbps2;
@FXML
private Label lblms;
@FXML
private AnchorPane rootPane;

AnchorPane netView;
String downloadSpeed = "";
String uploadSpeed = "";

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    lblPingNum.setText(getPing());
    lblms.setVisible(true);

    downloadSpeed = checkDownloadSpeed();
    lblDownloadNum.setText(downloadSpeed);
    lblmbps.setVisible(true);

    uploadSpeed = checkUploadSpeed();
    lblUploadNum.setText(uploadSpeed);
    lblmbps2.setVisible(true);

    try {netView = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("NetworkView.fxml"));}
    catch(Exception ex){} 
}

//Parsing a txt file for the first line first word
//Set selected node to a content holder
private void setNode(Node node) {
    rootPane.getChildren().clear();
    rootPane.getChildren().add((Node) node);

    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1500));
    ft.setNode(node);
    ft.setFromValue(0.1);
    ft.setToValue(1);
    ft.setCycleCount(1);
    ft.setAutoReverse(false);
    ft.play();
}

//Creates new Stage and scene to display second Gui Window
//Passes control to the NetworkViewController
@FXML
private void changeSceneButtonPushed(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    setNode(netView);
}
```

}

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: [`process.waitFor(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) ???

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest